# Are Delphi record constructors really needed?

Tags: delphi, constructor, records

**SITUATION**

I am studying "More Coding in Delphi" by Nick Hodges, and he is using a `TFraction` record to explain operator overloading.  I have written by myself this record:

```
type
  TFraction = record
  strict private
    aNumerator: integer;
    aDenominator: integer;
    function GCD(a, b: integer): integer;
  public
    constructor Create(aNumerator: integer; aDenominator: integer);
    procedure Reduce;
    class operator Add(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
    class operator Subtract(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
    //... implicit, explicit, multiply...
    property Numerator: integer read aNumerator;
    property Denominator: integer read aDenominator;
  end;
```

Of course, I had to create a constructor because in Q (rationals) I must have a denominator that is not equal to zero.

```
constructor TFraction.Create(aNumerator, aDenominator: integer);
begin
  if (aDenominator = 0) then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Denominator cannot be zero in rationals!');
  end;

  if ( (aNumerator < 0) or (aDenominator < 0) ) then
  begin
    Self.aNumerator := -aNumerator;
    Self.aDenominator := -aDenominator;
  end
  else
  begin
    Self.aNumerator := aNumerator;
    Self.aDenominator := aDenominator;
  end;
end;
```

---

**PROBLEM**

Since the operator overloads return a `TFraction`, I am going to define an operation like this:

```
class operator TFraction.Add(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
var
  tmp: TFraction;
begin
  //simple algorithm of the sum
  tmp := TFraction.Create(fraction1.Numerator*fraction2.Denominator+fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Numerator, fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Denominator);
  tmp.Reduce;

  //return the result
  Result := tmp;
end;
```

As you can see here, I am creating a `tmp` that is returned from the function.

When I read Marco Cantu's book, he used another approach:

```
class operator TFraction.Add(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
begin
  Result.aNumerator := (fraction1.Numerator*fraction2.Denominator+fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Numerator);
  Result.aDenominator := fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Denominator;
end;
```

I have made some tests, and I see that both give me the correct result, but there is something that I cannot understand.  In the first approach, I am declaring *tmp* and then I call the constructor so I can return a `TFraction`. In the second approach, I am instead not creating anything because records have an automatic constructor.  The documentation, in fact, says that:

> Records are constructed automatically, using a default no-argument
>   constructor, but classes must be explicitly constructed. Because
>   records have a default no-argument constructor, any user-defined
>   record constructor must have one or more parameters.

Here I have a user-defined record constructor. So:

1. Is the constructor call on `tmp` of the first approach not needed? If I want to call `Reduce` (which is a procedure), I need to create a variable. Is the `Result` just returning a copy of `tmp` without creating anything?
2. In the second approach, are `Result.aNumerator` and `Result.aDenominator` the parameters of the automatic created constructor?

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's typically normal practice to use `F` as the prefix for private fields in a class, and a prefix of `A` for method parameters (which you do use). In Delphi, it's just fine, but apparently, in Lazarus, that would not compile.

Comment: Ok thank you I didn't know, I am using a for parameters and variables. I will change my habit!

Comment: @Jerry What do you mean. FPC doesn't enforce naming convention rules.

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073767/why-does-a-valid-constructor-in-delphi-fail-in-lazarus

Comment: @jerry I'm not sure I believe that. I suspect that Remy's comment has the right information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A record constructor isn't anything magical. It's just an instance method like any other. You write:

```
tmp := TFraction.Create(...);
```

But you may equally well write it like this:

```
tmp.Create(...);
```

I personally find neither to be especially useful because I am used to constructor calling semantics for classes which allocate and default initialise memory, and then call the constructor method.

And especially the second variant grates with me because that looks like the classic mistake that novice Delphi programmers make when starting out and trying to create an instance of a class. That code would be no good if `TFraction` were a class, but for a record it is fine.

Were it me I would get rid of the record constructor and instead use a static class function that returned a newly minted instance of your record type. My convention is to name such things `New`. But these are matters of personal preference.

If you did that it would be declared like this:

```
class function New(aNumerator, aDenominator: Integer): TFraction; static;
```

It would be implemented like this:

```
class function TFraction.New(aNumerator, aDenominator: Integer): TFraction;
begin
  Result.aNumerator := ...;
  Result.aDenominator := ...;
end;
```

You would then call it like this:

```
frac := TFraction.New(num, denom);
```

But as I said, that's a matter of preference. If you like record constructors, feel free to stick with them.

---

You ask whether or not you can skip the constructor. In terms of allocation of the record, yes you can skip it. In terms of running the code in the constructor, only you can determine that. Do you want that code to execute or not?

If you wish that code to be executed, but don't want to use a temporary variable, then you can write the code like this:

```
class operator TFraction.Add(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
begin
  Result.Create(
    fraction1.Numerator*fraction2.Denominator + fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Numerator,
    fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Denominator
  );
  Result.Reduce;
end;
```

Or if you preferred a static class function it would be:

```
class operator TFraction.Add(fraction1, fraction2: TFraction): TFraction;
begin
  Result := TFraction.New(
    fraction1.Numerator*fraction2.Denominator + fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Numerator,
    fraction1.Denominator*fraction2.Denominator
  );
  Result.Reduce;
end;
```

Comment: I prefer the constructor way because it seems cleaner to me. Nick is doing exactly what you are suggesting to me with the class function

Comment: Also I didnt know about the Result thing. Is it treated like a normal variable? I see that you can call the Reduce on it!

Comment: IMO constructors on records are misleading (in general). There is no way to make sure it will ever be used. A record is a "value", not an object.

Comment: I helped nick a little bit with that chapter. It seems you know just what Result is because to use it in your code. When you assign to it. It's just an implicit var param which holds the return value.

Comment: As far as using record constructors goes, don't complain what you get confused and call obj.Create where obj is a class reference!! I recall discussing this with Nick when he was writing the chapter.

Comment: Reading the preface I have just seen that a certain David Heffernan suggested Nick to use the fractions example, do you know him? ;)

Comment: I am going in the deep of the class operator thing in the record vs the constructor, if I have doubts I'll make a proper question.

Comment: There's no right or wrong here. It does come down to preference. No need to get too hung up on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if I want to keep the record attributes as private then the use of  constructor to pass attribute values is the only way because using a class method you can only access the public attributes. Right?

Comment: @delmo No. In fact the code in my answer demonstrates a class method accessing strict private fields.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the fields aNumerator and aDenominator are declarated **strict private** by the OP and you didn't change that in your answer. Strict-private fields can't be accessed from a class method so in this specific case would be better to use a constructor. Right?

Comment: @Delmo As I said, the code in my answer demonstrates a class method accessing strict private fields. Clearly you have a misconception. Compiling the code in my answer might help you overcome that.

Comment: tmp.Create and tmp := TFraction.Create(...) are different...... tmp.Create directly operates on the tmp instance.  tmp := TFraction.Create would first create an additional TEMPORARY value then copy-assign that value to tmp